# silk full screen actual resolution on kindle hdx

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

OK, the silk browser goes 'full screen'. But there is a margin. Argh! Can I get rid of the margin, or get it into full full screen (2560 X 1600)? Or find out what the actual size is (2560-mw,1600-mw) ?

I am going to have to write my html to handle this. But maybe there is some setting on the Kindle Silk browser that tells the full screen mode to not have that margin.

Why do I not want the margin? Because I have an image exactly 2560 X 1600, and I want to view it full screen, pixel for pixel.

Comment: As of currently written, this looks more like a development-related question, since I'm not sure why end-user might care about the margin in pixel. Could you explain what you're trying to do with that? We could probably answer regarding full "full screen" though.

Comment: OK, it is a css thing. Needs border:0px;